# Installed application on PC with API - how can we identify the endpoint to access the API from internet

Tags: soapui, endpoint

We've just installed an application with SQL database which has an API which can be accessed from the web with SoapUI.

The application is installed on what's essentially a home PC with a dynamic IP address from a wifi network.

- How can we identify what the endpoint is to use SoapUI to access from other locations?

Comment: You would have to use something like DynDNS. Exposing a home network to the internet like that is a security risk. I would strongly suggest getting an entry-level hosted machine for this.

Comment: ngrok will also get the job done